# Document Library Content type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, document-template

How does a Content Type in the Document library usefull? If new Content Type Template is added how to apply the existing Columns to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many articles explaining this concept, however one of the main benefits of content types are defining specific columns / fields that are associated with a type of content. For example if you defined a "Quaterly Report" content type, you could associate the columns "Year" and "Quater" with all quaterly reports.

From Microsoft:

> Content types are first defined centrally in the Site Content Type
>   Gallery for a site. Content types that are defined at the site level
>   are called site content types. Site content types are available for
>   use in any subsites of the site for which they have been defined. For
>   example, if a site content type is defined in the Site Content Type
>   Gallery for the top-level site in a site collection, it is available
>   for use in lists and libraries in all of the sites in that site
>   collection. Site content types can be added individually to lists or
>   libraries and customized for use in those lists or libraries. When an
>   instance of a site content type is added to a list or library, it is
>   called a list content type. List content types are children of the
>   site content types from which they are created.
>
> When you add a content type to a list or library, you make it possible
>   for that list or library to contain items of that type. The New
>   command in that list or library lets users create new items of that
>   type. One of the key advantages of content types for lists and
>   libraries is that they make it possible for a single list or library
>   to contain multiple item types or document types, each of which may
>   have unique metadata, policies, or behaviors.

To add an existing column to a content type:

Go to site settings > Site content types and locate your content type you wish to modify.

Then towards the bottom of that screen you will see "Add from existing site columns".